# Backbone fetch returns 5 models but when I render my collection view only 1 model exists?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I make a `fetch` and log the response my I can see 5 objects, but, when I log out the data in the view where I'm listening for the collection sync event only 1 object is logged out? My data is store in a `global dataStore object` as `dataStore.videos`, an anyone explain where I might be going wrong?

**VideoSearchCollection.js**

```
getVideos: function(searchTerm) {

            this.searchTerm = searchTerm;

            this.fetch();
        },
parse: function(response) {

            console.log('this is response.items: ', response.items); // logs 5

            return response.items;
        }
```

**SearchResultsView.js**

```
initialize: function() {

            // listens to a change in the collection by the sync event and calls the render method
            this.listenTo(dataStore.videos, 'sync', this.render);

            console.log('This collection should look like this: ', dataStore.videos);
        },


        render: function() {

            console.log('inside render', dataStore.videos); // logs 1??

            var self = this,
                gridFragment = this.createItems();

                this.$el.html(gridFragment);

            return this;
        },
```

**My data**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The id matters. Looks like your server response is returning items that does not have id so Backbone merge all of them into one.

Wrong server response:

```
{"name","dan 1"}
{"name","dan 2"}
```

Right server response:

```
{"name","dan 1", id: 1}
{"name","dan 2", id: 2}
```

Comment: oh yeah, when i look at my data there is no actual ids, ive attached a screenshot of my data in the post above now. what can i do about this?

Comment: As told you, id matters. In your case, id is an object, Backbone expects ID to be string or number to be unique. Are you able to modify server code so you can return videoId as id? if not, in the parse function for your model, map id = as videoId, something like it.

Comment: this is data coming back from the youtube api so I cant update it, il try parsing the model though, thanks!